# Post that populates itself (almost) automatically using data from imported excel file

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, posts, functions, mysql

What I mean is...

I'm trying to Import an Excel file with 1000s of data into Wordpress.
That's the easy part, there are plugins that import excel data.

I also want for each "data" to create a post with certain fields already at default, automatically some way, cause we're talking about 1000s of entries not mere 100s...

For example... One entry would look like this:

```
   Title            Author           Editor            ISBN

(Book title)    (Book Author)    (Book Editor)    (16 digit ISBN)
```

And so far I've found a simple way to add something automatically every time I create a new post using the functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'default_content', 'my_editor_content' );
function my_editor_content( $content ) {
$content = " (my-content-here) ";
return $content;
}
```

which adds (my-content-here) into every post I make.

What i want to do though, if it's possible, cause again there are many entries, is if for each post I create I can get the title/author/editor/isbn automatically, the same way like above, from data I've imported from the excel file... and make them look like this:

```
                       (Title in bold)



                Author(s):

                Editor:

                ISBN: 


                Back cover presentation:
```

And the thing that I'll have to do is correct any mistakes each post may have and/or add more things that need to be added like an image on top of the title...

Right now I'm using the [Custom Post Type UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) for the custom post types like
Fantasy books, or Science books, etc. So that each Category of books is it's own post type.

Edit: Also do I need Custom Fields to achieve what I'm suggesting? like the Advanced Custom Fields plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a single "book" post type would be most appropriate. You could then add custom postmeta, which does not require Advanced Custom Fields. I would create the post type and custom fields first, test them out to make sure they're saving appropriately to the database. Then, you can do a foreach loop for each line in your CSV, and use [wp_insert_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) which has a `meta_input` parameter where you can add all the corresponding custom fields (postmeta).

Comment: custom postmeta? Also... 

I lost you here " Then, you can do a foreach loop for each line in your CSV, and use wp_insert_post which has a meta_input parameter where you can add all the corresponding custom fields (postmeta). "

how am I gonna do a for each loop for a CSV? .... I'm gonna try and test the custom postmeta you said :D ... Thanks a lot for your suggestion!

Comment: Look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269562/how-to-create-an-array-from-a-csv-file-using-php-and-the-fgetcsv-function/#1269615 - read the CSV into an array, then you can do foreach. Lots of work to do here but you'll learn a ton about custom post types, custom postmeta, and CSV manipulation. :)